# If $2−\cos^2θ=3\sinθ\cosθ$ then $\sin \theta \neq\cos\theta$ then $\tan \theta$ is…

Tags: trigonometry

If $2−\cos^2θ=3\sinθ\cosθ$ then $\sin \theta\neq \cos\theta$ then $\tan \theta$ is …

What is $\tanθ$?

My work is: $2−\cos^2θ=3\sinθ\cosθ$

$2\sinθ\cosθ=\sin2θ$ or dividing both sides by $\cosθ$ or $\sinθ$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if $\sin\theta=\cos\theta$, then either both are $1/\sqrt{2}$ or both are $-1/\sqrt{2}$; but in these cases
$$
2-\cos^2\theta=2-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}
\qquad
3\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{3}{2}
$$
so your starting point is wrong. Probably your statement is

> If $2-\cos^2\theta=3\sin\theta\cos\theta$ ***and*** $\sin\theta\ne\cos\theta$, compute $\tan\theta$.

You can use $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, so your equality becomes
$$
2\cos^2\theta+2\sin^2\theta-\cos^2\theta=3\sin\theta\cos\theta
$$
that can be written
$$
2\sin^2\theta-3\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta=0
$$
Observe that $\cos^2\theta\ne0$ (which also tells you that $\tan\theta$ is defined), so you can divide by $\cos^2\theta$ getting
$$
2\tan^2\theta-3\tan\theta+1=0
$$
Can you go on? The hypothesis $\sin\theta\ne\cos\theta$ tells you that $\tan\theta\ne1$.

Comment: so $tan \theta=1/2$

Comment: @jyothika Yes: the equation $2t^2-3t+1=0$ has the solutions $t=1$ and $t=1/2$; but $\tan\theta\ne1$, so $\tan\theta=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If you have meant $\cos^2\theta,$ divide either sides by $\cos^2\theta$ and write $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$

If you have meant $\cos2\theta,$ write $\cos2\theta=\dfrac{1-\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$
and $\sin\theta\cos\theta=\dfrac{\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}$

Comment: @jyothika, $$\sin A\cos A=\frac{\sin A\cos A/\cos^2A}{\sec^2A}=?$$

Comment: @jyothika, Derived from the double angle formula

Comment: @jyothika, Yes:)

Comment: when i use  sinθ cosθ=tanθ/1+tan^2θ then sec^2θ=1+tan^2θ.something went wrong

Comment: @jyothika, Please pinpoint the mistake. The case does not arise though as we have $\cos^2\theta,$ not $\cos2\theta$

Answer (score 0):

As @labbhattacharjee said

$2/cos^2\theta-1=3 sin\theta/cos\theta$

$2/cos^2\theta-1=3 tan\theta$

$2sec^2\theta-1=3 tan\theta$

$2tan^2\theta=3tan\theta$

so $tan\theta=3/2$. I am getting $tan \theta=3/2$ is this correct or not.if wrong explain from the method i used above.

Comment: Wrong, sorry. The answer is $\tan\theta=1/2$

Comment: @egreg i need to know whether my steps are correct

Comment: $\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}=1+\tan^2\theta$, so you get $2+2\tan^2\theta-1=3\tan\theta$, which is the same equation I got in my answer.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee see the above method